# Mysql query with GROUP BY and MAX, wrong result returned

Tags: mysql

I have strange results with my query:

```
SELECT 
  veicoli_ID, 
  MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS mmax, 
  EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione 
FROM revisioni_veicolo 
GROUP BY veicoli_ID 
HAVING StatoUltimaRevisione = 1
```

I have create the fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d97cd/1

Why `StatoUltimaRevisione` column return always true? I think must be false for IDs 20 and 26.

EXPECTED (**without**: `HAVING StatoUltimaRevisione = 1`):

```
veicoli_ID     mmax     StatoUltimaRevisione
6           2019-08-01  true
7           2018-04-09  true
20          2018-12-01  false
26          2020-10-01  false
44          2019-09-01  true
45          2020-05-01  true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you get are *"correct"* according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).
The logic you try to apply though, does not work.
You have in the `SELECT` list the column `EsitoPositivo` which is not included in the `GROUP BY` clause and it is not aggregated (with `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` etc) and you think that the value returned for the column `EsitoPositivo` will be the one from the row with the `MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione)`, but **this is not guaranteed**.
Why? Because:

> ...the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless
>   they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic...

So the values chosen for `EsitoPositivo` is any value from the group it belongs to.

You must change this logic of your query by using a join of the table to a query that returns only `veicoli_ID` and `MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione)`:

```
SELECT r.veicoli_ID, g.mmax, r.EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione 
FROM revisioni_veicolo r INNER JOIN (
  SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS mmax
  FROM revisioni_veicolo
  GROUP BY veicoli_ID 
) g ON g.veicoli_ID = r.veicoli_ID AND g.mmax = r.DataScadenzaRevisione
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
  r.veicoli_ID, 
  r.DataScadenzaRevisione AS mmax, 
  r.EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione 
FROM revisioni_veicolo r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM revisioni_veicolo
  WHERE veicoli_ID = r.veicoli_ID AND DataScadenzaRevisione > r.DataScadenzaRevisione
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7cf476e3d6dd145f1874b3e0148bd38e).
Results:

```
> veicoli_ID | mmax       | StatoUltimaRevisione
> ---------: | :--------- | -------------------:
>          6 | 2019-08-01 |                    1
>          7 | 2018-04-09 |                    1
>         20 | 2018-12-01 |                    0
>         26 | 2020-10-01 |                    0
>         44 | 2019-09-01 |                    1
>         45 | 2020-05-01 |                    1
```

Comment: thank you for explanation. Now i'm trying to merge the code with the other piece of my  old code but I get syntax error and I don't find the problem. Can you help me with the fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c77eb2/20  My goal is to have these 3 new dynamic fields compiled for every vehicle: StatoUltimaRevisione, RevisioneScaduta, RevisionePresente

Comment: The comments section is not the place to ask questions. Post this as a new question, provide the sample data with the fiddle, explain what you are trying to do and very important: post the expected results.

Comment: hi i've added it to a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609808/nested-join-to-create-custom-dynamic-columns can you help me?

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: thank you. i've forgot to translate some parts in english for the fiddle. I hope you undestand fields name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT veicoli_ID
       , MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS mmax
       , case when min(EsitoPositivo) = 0 then 'false'
         else 'true'
         end StatoUltimaRevisione
FROM revisioni_veicolo
GROUP BY veicoli_ID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d97cd/33)

Comment: Hi, this work ok. So...my logic is incorrect? I need to retrieve all data columns of the row where MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) is achieved..

Comment: Happy to see you have found a correct answer but I do not understand why my answer is not marked as correct for your original question ...

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. but someone has downvoted it...so result is 0

Comment: I am not talking about that I am talking about the correct answer. That is vote up or down... My demo returns the results you asked for. EXACTLY you asked for and it gives a true fals results...

Answer (score 0):

Found result:

```
 SELECT a.veicoli_ID, a.EsitoPositivo, a.DataScadenzaRevisione
FROM revisioni_veicolo a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS MaxDataScadenzaRevisione
    FROM revisioni_veicolo
    GROUP BY veicoli_ID
) b ON a.veicoli_ID = b.veicoli_ID AND a.DataScadenzaRevisione = b.MaxDataScadenzaRevisione
```